# How do I bind Seq[String] parameter in sqlu query?

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

How do I bind `Seq[String]` parameter in `sqlu` query ?

I'l like to pass string container to the query. My query looks like this in plain sql

```
update public.users set topic_ids = array_append(topic_ids, 'one') 
where id = E'\\x55ef630a590801000126136e' and ('{one}' && topic_ids) = true
```

I tried following versions of code

```
val userId: ObjectId = ... // I have SetParameter[ObjectId] for it
val topicId: String = "blah"

// Fails with: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 3, number of columns: 2.
sqlu"update public.users set topic_ids = array_append(topic_ids, $topicId::text) where id = $userId && ('$topicId' && topic_ids) = true"

// Fails with "could not find implicit value for parameter e: slick.jdbc.SetParameter[Seq[String]]"
sqlu"update public.users set topic_ids = array_append(topic_ids, $topicId::text) where id = $userId && (${Seq(topicId)}::text[] && topic_ids) = true"

// Fails with "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bytea && boolean"
sqlu"update public.users set topic_ids = array_append(topic_ids, $topicId::text) where id = $userId && ('{#$topicId}' && topic_ids) = true"
```

I would have created `SetParameter[Seq[String]]` but there is no setter that sets array.

How can I implement this ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm in the same pickle.

Comment: @JordanParmer Unfortunately I couldn't find elegant solution and ended up switching to ScalikeJDBC to use 9.5 features.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up implementing a hack. I used plain SQL and fully expanded the query string into a variable (I didn't bind any variables but constructed the string in memory) and then used `sql"#$queryString"`. It works for what I need although not elegant and shouldn't ever be used with user input. Thankfully this is a back-end process.